# Substring, Split, String to Number and RGB to HEX

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, ecmascript-6

I thought this was an easy task but it is getting really complex. See the Code.

```
    // Convert "rgb(255, 255, 255)" to (255, 255, 255) and then to Hex code
    var data = {
        color:"rgb(165,199,72)",
        color:"rgb(229,121,74)",
        color:"rgb(105,177,222)"        
    }
    // rgb To Hex Conversion
    var componentToHex = function(c) {            
        var hex = c.toString(16);
        return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
    }       
    var rgbHex = function(r, g, b) {
        return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
    }


    //Substring "rgb(255, 255, 255)" to "(255, 255, 255)"
    var subStringRGB = function(c){
        var b = c.substring(4, c.length);
    }
    var stringRGBtoNumber = function(c){
        var b = Number(c.split(','));
    }
```

It is throwing error, cannot read split of undefined. How to fix this?

Comment: you object literal is not valid, it overwrites the first two properties with the content of the last, in best case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could the functions combine to a singe line with spread operator and some mapping of parts of the values.

`subStringRGB` and `stringRGBtoNumber` returns now the processed value.

```js
var data = [{ color:"rgb(165,199,72)"}, { color:"rgb(229,121,74)" },{ color:"rgb(105,177,222)" }],        
    componentToHex = function(c) {            
        var hex = c.toString(16);
        return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
    },
    rgbHex = function(r, g, b) {
        return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
    },
    subStringRGB = function(c){
        return c.slice(4, -1);
    },
    stringRGBtoNumber = function(c){
        return c.split(',').map(Number); // split and convert all parts to Number
    };
    
console.log(data.map(c => rgbHex(...stringRGBtoNumber(subStringRGB(c.color)).map(componentToHex))));
```

Answer (score 2):

`subStringRGB` does not a return a value. So, if you pass the result of `subStringRGB` to `stringRGBtoNumber` `c` will probably be `undefined` in `stringRGBtoNumber`. By the way, `stringRGBtoNumber` does not return a value, too.

Answer (score 1):

Processing it with Regular Expression is easy.

```js
var arr = /rgb(\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+)\))/.exec("rgb(255,255,255)");
console.log(arr[1]); // it shows (255,255,255)
var hexVal = (parseInt(arr[2]) << 16) + (parseInt(arr[3]) << 8) + parseInt(arr[4]); // calculate the decimal value
console.log("0x" + hexVal.toString(16)); // it shows 0xffffff
```

Comment: I'd make two changes: `var hexVal = arr[2]<<16 | arr[3]<<8 | arr[4];` imo it's simpler and `console.log("#" + (0x1000000 | hexVal).toString(16).substr(1));` to print a proper color in hex-notation (and leading zeroes are important here)